# How to fix broken tooltips in the Sources tab of Chrome debugger (i.e. dev-tools)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

For a long time, I have not been able to use tooltips in the Sources tab of the chrome debugger anymore. Today I thought that I found a fix (which I posted below) but now tooltips have stopped working again. So, maybe someone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In Settings/General of the debugger I disabled "Show detailed inspect tooltip". Then I reloaded Chrome and enabled "Show detailed inspect tooltip". Somehow, this caused tooltips to work again.

Unfortunately, not long after, tooltips stopped working again.